# working of std::bitset in cpp

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to know how is this program working:

```html
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
 
const int option_1 = 0;
const int option_2 = 1;
const int option_3 = 2;
const int option_4 = 3;
const int option_5 = 4;
const int option_6 = 5;
const int option_7 = 6;
const int option_8 = 7;
 
int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> bits(0x2); 
    bits.set(option_5);
    bits.flip(option_6); 
    bits.reset(option_6); 
 
    std::cout << "Bit 4 has value: " << bits.test(option_5) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Bit 5 has value: " << bits.test(option_6) << '\n';
    std::cout << "All the bits: " << bits << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen this example on a website, But cannot understand the working of some part of this program.
here, first option5 is set to 4, then in main program "bit.set(option5);" is used to set it to 1(is what i think). then what is use of that 4 assigned to integer option5 above??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is basically at a high level an array of bits. Using non type templating an array of bits is created on the stack.

The `option5` variable is used to set the fourth bit (from the back when printed) to 1. So when you print out the values there is a 1 in the location pointed to by `option5` which is location 4 from the back.

The constructor of the bitset is used to initialize the bitset to look like 0b00000010. The `set()` function sets the bit at the location specified to 1, the `reset()` function sets the bit at the location specified to 0.

Comment: so in simple language, u mean that 4 is a address and not a value. am i right??

Comment: In a way yes! It is pointing to a location in the bitfield :) Very much like an index to an array